# Adjusting UIITabBar properties?

Tags: uitabbar, uitabbaritem, uistoryboard

I am upgrading an iPhone app to Universal, and found that all the UITabBarItems squeezed in the center.

I am using the new storyboard feature in Xcode, can I adjust any properties for UITabBarItems or UITabBar itself to control things like the width of the tab bar items - or simply fill up the whole width of UITabBar like the iPhone?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could just place flexible space bar button items between those buttons in the interface builder dynamically

Comment: I thought the flexible space bar is for Toolbar not TabBar? Anyway I tried dragging the flexible space bar over and it does not work.

Comment: Oh! I misread your question. Sorry about that. The only thing I can think of right now is perhaps the view meant for iPad is displaying in iPhone. I believe you are using two separate views for the iPad and iPhone ?

Comment: Yes, I am using 2 separate views. The iPhone one works fine, for iPad all the tabs are squeezed in the center which is the default behavior - but I would really like the tabs to spread out to fill the width just like the iPhone version.

Comment: Indeed, I have never attempted that. Why not create a custom toolbar and put the flexible space in between the buttons then implement the buttons' touchUpInside event to the switch to the tabs' corresponding controller. This may sounds like extra code but the implementation is quite easy and will surely get the job done! I can provide sample codes if necessary. Hope this helps!